# C# use reflection to modify a running process

Tags: reflection

I want to use reflection to get and set properties etc. I know how to do this for an object I instance myself using Activator.CreateInstance(), but how do I attach to an already running process in memory and do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is possible.

But if you have the source of the process you want to control, you could use remoting or wcf.